# Count the duplicates in list of dict in django python

Tags: python, django

How can i find the count of duplicates in this list.

```
>>> result = SiteTags.objects.values('content_type','object_id')
>>> result
[{'object_id': 1, 'content_type': 46}, {'object_id': 1, 'content_type': 46}, {'object_id': 2, 'content_type': 42}]
```

Is there anyway to find in query? or through an other way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set(tuple(sorted(r.iteritems())) for r in result)
```

gives you a set of unique elements in this list. Take its length and compare it to `len(result)`.

To get each element and its count within the result:

```
counter = {}
for r in result:
    tup = tuple(sorted(r.iteritems()))
    counter[tup] = counter.get(tup, 0) + 1
for tup, cnt in counter.iteritems():
    print dict(tup), cnt
```

prints:

```
{'object_id': 2, 'content_type': 42} 1
{'object_id': 1, 'content_type': 46} 2
```

Answer (score 6):

If I'm understanding your request correctly, *[collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)* would be a useful way to count the duplicates.  It works only with hashable inputs, so you dictionaries in your list need to be converted tuples of sorted items:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in result])
Counter({(('content_type', 46), ('object_id', 1)): 2, (('content_type', 42), ('object_id', 2)): 1})
```

It probably goes without saying that the duplicates are the entries with counts greater than one :-)

Comment: `Counter` is not in Python 2.6

Comment: I know.  I wrote it :-)   The good news is I also wrote a backport.  See http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577664-counter-class/ for a version that runs on Python 2.5 or later.   P.S.  When posting a Python question, be sure to mention that you're on 2.6; otherwise, respondents will assume you've got the current version of Python.

Comment: I'm continually amazed by the number of, shall we say, high-profile people I run into on SO :)